# How can I scan strings with multiple words multiple times in C [not C++]?

Tags: c, string, fgets, gets

I have googled many times but I cannot find a concrete answer to my question/problem.
I know fgets() allows it, as well as gets(). But if i do it multiple times, there's always an error. Multiple times mean, e.g. I want to ask for his first name, then his middle name, then his surname which can be 1 or more strings.

I think I got it by using gets since I can't make fgets() work, but there's some bug in my program. So, I wanna ask for a better solution than what I did. Anyway, here's the partial code:

```
BST *insert(BST *root, BST *temp){
    if(root == NULL) root = temp; //empty
    else{
        temp->parent = root;
        //if true i = 1, else i = 0
        int i = root->employee.emnumber <= temp->employee.emnumber;
        //recurse
        root->child[i] = insert(root->child[i], temp);
    }
    return root;
}

int checknum(BST *root, int num){
    if(root == NULL){
        if(num <= 99999 && num >= 1) return 0;
        else return 1;
    }
    if(root->employee.emnumber == num || num > 99999 || num < 1) return 1;

    int i = root->employee.emnumber <= num;
    checknum(root->child[i], num);
}

BST *add(BST *root){
    int invalid = -1;
    BST *temp = malloc (sizeof (BST) );
    temp->child[0] = temp->child[1] = temp->parent = NULL;

    printf("\n\tADD EMPLOYEE INFORMATION\n");
    printf("\nEnter Employee Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.emnumber) );
    invalid = checknum(root,temp->employee.emnumber);
    if(invalid) printf("\nInvalid Input!\n(Either your input is not a 5-digit number or the employee number is already in the database)\n\n");
    else{
        printf("\nFull Name| First Name: ");
        getchar();
        gets(temp->employee.emname.fn);
        //printf("%d\n", strlen(temp->employee.emname.fn));
        if(strlen(temp->employee.emname.fn) > max) printf("Invalid Input!\n(Input only %d characters)\n", max);
        else{
            printf("           Middle Name: ");
            gets(temp->employee.emname.mn);
            if(strlen(temp->employee.emname.mn) > max) printf("Invalid Input!\n(Input only %d characters)\n", max);
            else{
                printf("           Last Name: ");
                gets(temp->employee.emname.ln);
                if(strlen(temp->employee.emname.ln) > max) printf("Invalid Input!\n(Input only %d characters)\n", max);
                else{
                    printf("\nBirth Date| Month: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.bdate.month) );
                    printf("            Day: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.bdate.day) );
                    printf("            Year: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.bdate.year) );
                    printf("\nCurrent Address: ");
                    scanf("%s", temp->employee.address);
                    printf("\nMonthly Gross Salary: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.salary) );
                    printf("\nHire Date| Month: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.hired.month) );
                    printf("           Day: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.hired.day) );
                    printf("           Year: ");
                    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.hired.year) );
                    root = insert(root, temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The bug is that if I entered an invalid number in add.Let's say I input 5 in employee number but there's employee number 5 already, the program will say that there's already employee 5 but if i print the employee list employee 5 is not there. Entering 5 again in add will not prompt you because it deleted employee 5. I do not how it is deleted since i did not call the delete function.
Please someone help me.

edit:
I removed checknum and did the search in my search function for delete:
my code for search is:

```
BST *search(BST *root, int x){
    int i;
    if(root == NULL || root->employee.emnumber == x) return(root);
    i = root->employee.emnumber <= x;
    return search(root->child[i], x);
}
```

and add is now:

```
BST *add(BST *root){
    BST *invalid = NULL;
    BST *temp = malloc (sizeof (BST) );
    temp->child[0] = temp->child[1] = temp->parent = NULL;

    printf("\n\tADD EMPLOYEE INFORMATION\n");
    printf("\nEnter Employee Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &(temp->employee.emnumber) );
    if(temp->employee.emnumber > 99999 || temp->employee.emnumber < 1)
        printf("\nInvalid Input!\n(Input only 5-digit number)\n\n");
    else{
        invalid = search(root,temp->employee.emnumber);
        if(invalid != NULL) printf("\nInvalid Input!\n(Already in the database)\n\n");
        else{
           /*The same codes here*/
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem now lies on what it returns to root when it encounters an "invalid input."
I call add() by root=add(root) so if it encountered a problem it points to null or something else.
So what do you think must I do?

EDIT [LAST]:
The problem really lies in what add() returns if it encountered the "invalid input." I changed BST *add to void add to avoid the root=add(root) then did the necessary changes in the function and now it works. Thanks for your answers, but I cannot give a check mark since I think no one answered it right. I'm now making it go with fgets().

Comment: You shouldn't use `gets` under any circumstances.  It's easy for your user to (accidentally or on purpose) overrun your buffer.

Comment: sadly, I encountered many problems using fgets()

Comment: "encounter[ing] many problems" is a circumstance.  See jonsca's comment.  DO NOT USE GETS

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with: what is returned from `checknum()` if it needs to recurse down by checking against the child?

Or, equivalently, did you compile with `-Wall` or your compiler's equivalent of activating all warnings?  What warnings were there?

Comment: checknum returns 0 and 1 as value for invalid. If invalid = 0 then it will continue if 1 then it will prompt the user.There are no warnings actually, you can see the bug when you're running the program, like I've said if an invalid number is entered, in this problem - a duplicate, it will delete the said employee information. I think it is really deleted since I cannot see it after printing the whole BST

Comment: If there are no warnings, you should probably get a better compiler.  Failing that, you need to read the `checknum()` code more carefully until you see the bug.  Seriously -- this is the #1 debugging skill that you need to learn!

Comment: John is correct, there should be a compiler warning for checknum.

Comment: Yeah I already did many things.Maybe I should try another compiler, I am currently using code::blocks. Time to reboot to linux

Comment: "_checknum returns 0 and 1 as value for invalid_" --  I asked what `checknum()` actually does in [certain circumstances].  Your answer is about what `checknum()` is intended to do.  This is the heart of your problem.

Comment: see edit...checknum() is not the problem here because checknum functions like my search function without the check if x is in the range (00001-99999). the problem, I think, lies on what add returns to root if encountered the invalid input thing.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` at the end of your `checknum()` function:

```
  int i = root->employee.emnumber <= num;
  return checknum(root->child[i], num);        //Added a return here
}
```

Without a `return` the recursive call to `checknum()` has no effect and the ultimate return value will probably not be what you want. Your compiler should have warned you about this assuming you have warnings turned on (typically something like "not all paths return a value").